# bigquery SQL - opposite of GREATEST() function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, multiple-columns, min

I am looking for a function that does the opposite of GREATEST() in Bigquery. Ex.:

| ID | date_1 | date_2 | date_3 | date_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-10-01 | 1987-12-25 | 1945-10-01 |
| 2 | 2009-05-30 | 2007-02-30 | 2015-10-15 | 1999-12-31 |

```
SELECT ID,
GREATEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4) AS MAX
FROM mytable
```

Output:

| ID | MAX |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 |
| 2 | 2015-10-15 |

What I want is something like:

```
 SELECT ID,
LOWEST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4) AS MIN
FROM mytable
```

Desired output:

| ID | MIN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1945-10-01 |
| 2 | 1999-12-31 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function LEAST().

```
SELECT ID,
LEAST(date_1,date_2,date_3,date_4) AS MAX
FROM mytable
```